# How to fixed it? Pascal main.pas(21,6) Fatal : syntax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found

Tags: if-statement, syntax, pascal

Help me please

```
program number_three;

uses crt;

var
i, j : integer;

begin
  for i := 1  to 5 do
  begin
    if (i mod 2 = 0) then
      begin   
        for j := 1  to 5 do  
        begin  
          if (j mod 2 = 0) then    
            begin       
              write('x ');    
            end    
          else  
            begin    
              write('o ');
            end
        end;   
    else   
      begin    
        for j := 1  to 5 do    
          begin   
            if (j mod 2 = 0) then
              begin     
                write('o ');     
              end
            else
          begin
            write('x '); 
          end 
       end;
    writeln('');
  end;
end.
```

Final result must be :

X O X O X O

O X O X O X

X O X O X O

O X O X O X

X O X O X O

Help me please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. People won't do assignments for you, but they will help you understand. You will get more help if you can make your code easier for people to read. Check the Stack Overflow instructions for how to enter code. Click the question mark button and then Code.

Comment: Correct the indentation.  Then check that the `begin` and `end` symbols are balanced and in the right places.  It looks to me like they aren't.  (But maybe it is just the messed up indentation that is tricking me ...)

Comment: I've edited to improve readability. Perhaps you can help more by adding a comment ```(* Error here *)``` on the exact line that the compiler is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

The `end` before the `else` must not be followed by a semicolon `;`. In Pascal the semicolon is a statement *separator* more or less.

---

```
for i := 1 to 5 do
begin
  for j := 1 to 5 do
    if (i + j) mod 2 = 0 then
      write('X ')
    else
      write('O ');
  writeln('');
end;
```

Comment: For more details, see https://wiki.freepascal.org/IF